# each() iteration in conjuction with trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, each

I have this code:

```
function gamePlay(array){
    $.each(array, function(index, value){
        $("." + sounds[value]).trigger("play");
    });
}
```

The function gets an array with values (class names). I want to play a sound on each iteration of an array. But, instead I get all sounds playing at once. I've tried using setTimeout but it does the same thing again. I need something that will stop/pause the iteration until the triggering the sound is done.

Comment: what is the  duration of sounds?

Comment: It would be better to hook to the `ended` event and then `play` the next `audio` element. If you can add a HTML sample to the question I can give you an example of how to do this.

Comment: @Azzi they r 1/25 of a second may be..just beep sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set timeout function like this. assume that all sound tracts has same duration.

```
function gamePlay(array){

    var duration = 1000;  //1000ms

    $.each(array, function(index, value){
        (function(value, index){

           setTimeout(function(){

              $("." + sounds[value]).trigger("play");

            }, index * duration);

        })(value, index);      
    }
}
```

Comment: @theo No, it doesn't. This makes the completely invalid assumption that every sound is 1 second long.

Comment: @Tomalak my sounds are beeps, which are less than a second long, so it's not an assumption. Also, the code works without the inner function as well, i've just tried them both. So I've removed the inner function

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:-

```
function gamePlay(array){
    playSound(array, 0);
}

function playSound(array, index){
    if((index+1) < array.length){
        $("." + sounds[array[index]]).on('ended', function() { 
            playSound(array, ++index);
        });
    }
    $("." + sounds[array[index]]).trigger("play");
}
```

This is untested, but gives an idea of how to trigger the next sound after the previous has finished.